# In odoo15 which is the function that creates a stock_move_line while manually select a serial number and save it in an inventory transfor

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

[image: Manually selected serial number]

[image: stock_move_line]

I want to know which function is creating these stock move lines